# Css Problem with API iframe

Tags: api, css

I am using social login plugin for connect with my site. Its working fine, but I want to remove its mark like **Powered By XYZ**. I have tried display none with its class and id but it did not work because all part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".ajay iframe").contents().find("#branding").attr("style","display:none");
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not allowed. That would be a big security issue.

> Under the policy, a web browser permits scripts contained in a first
>   web page to access data in a second web page, but only if both web
>   pages have the same origin

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

If you are under control of the URL in the iframe, you are able to access the content by sending a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` Header.